# Flexbox remove the column gap between two children

Tags: html, css, frontend

This is the code:

```css
.content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: stretch;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <h4>type</h4>
    <h4>exp</h4>
</div>
```

This is what it looks like:

```
______________________

        type


        exp

______________________
```

How do I shrink the gap between the 2 elements?
I tried css **gap: 10px;** and **column-gap: 20px;**, it does not work.

Comment: I am using React, I don't know if there is a way to create an example for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spacing between the `h4` elements is because by default, `h4` has a margin around it. You can just add `margin: 0` to h4 to prevent this:

```css
.content {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-content: stretch;
}

.content h4 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <h4>type</h4>
    <h4>exp</h4>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `h4`-tag has some margin by default. Try to add

```css
h4 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

to your CSS.